# Unable to import module and its functions in Python

Tags: python, python-import

My directory structure is as follows:

```
-webapps
    --components
        --__init__.py
        --component1.py
        --component2.py
    --functions
        --__init__.py
        --function1.py
        --function2.py
```

function1.py and function2.py starts with

```
import sys
sys.path.append("../..")
from components import component1
```

Both __ init__.py are empty.

I can import component1 and its methods but I cannot import component2 and its methods. Can anyone point out what maybe wrong?

Comment: Are you sure you are not importing some other `component2` ? The `sys.path.append()` seems to be appending `webapps` parent into `sys.path` , which is not what you want, you should use - `sys.path.append('../')` . Also , what file are you running when getting this?

Comment: Yes, I don't have any other component2. Also, I changed it to 'sys.path.append("../")' but even that is not working. And I'm trying to run function1.py where I'm getting this issue.

Comment: Which python version are you running? Are you importing something relatively inside `component2` ?

Comment: I'm using Python 2.7.9 version. And I'm not importing anything relatively inside component2.

Comment: what error are you getting when trying to import component2 ?

Comment: ImportError: No module named component2

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90394/discussion-between-anand-s-kumar-and-shrikant-kakani).

Comment: Could the problem may be one with circular imports?
Can you tell me all your imports in component1.py, component2.py, function1.py and function2.py?

Comment: @p9teufel: there are no circular imports. But even if that's the problem, PyCharm should have still suggested the import, isn't it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed the above issue. So I've a directory at

```
/Users/skakani/Library/Caches/PyCharm40/python_stubs/2068767379/
```

that had these folders 'components' and 'functions' but it doesn't have any 'webapps' folder. Once I deleted those folders, everything started working as expected. These folders again had similar structure but I've no idea why ONLY these folders were created. Also, I don't know how /Users/skakani/Library/Caches/PyCharm40/python_stubs/2068767379/ structure also got created.

If you're facing the similar issue, then you should go to /Users/skakani/Library/Caches/PyCharm40/python_stubs/ folder and see what all subfolders it has.